# WordPress Widgets Off Site

Tags: php, wordpress, html, facebook

So let me start off by giving a little information on what I am doing, I am creating an HTML5 WebApp (full-screen mode) for a church that does audio productions and online ministry sermon video and non-video posts, I decided to build it on top of WordPress, so they can allow multiple user's to easily customize the content of the pages inside the webapp as well as, post new content. So WordPress is installed inside the root directory, the web app is in the /app directory. The only issue I am running into is there is a widget based plugin that feeds up the events from Facebook, its really well done and I want to use it in the webapp. I cannot figure out an easy way to serve it up to the webapp. My latest effort was to build it into a post and serve that particular post up over PHP, well that fails miserably because once it gets to the webapp it has no idea how to handle the shortcode other than as plain text.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');

<?php
$post_id = 17;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?>
```

Not sure why I thought that would work because obviously, it has no idea what the short code in the post is other than plain-text. Is there a file or files I can just include so that it will understand how to handle the widget and display it correctly or should I just get started on building what it does in its owns no dependency form?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
echo do_shortcode( $queried_post->post_content );
```

That should parse any shortcodes contained in the post content, and run them through their corresponding hooks.

Reference: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: So I have tried like 50 variations of this now, here is a jsfiddle of the page I am working on currently. which is inside a directory of the wordpress installation. Wordpress is in root I am in /application
https://jsfiddle.net/b9m0mga2/1/

Comment: To clarify, you're not getting any PHP errors? The only symptom is the shortcodes being output literally?